# Creating a counter within a getter/setter?

Tags: java, counter, setter, getter

I was wondering lets say I have the following getter/setter:

```
public class Age {
private int age;

    public void setAge(int count){
          this.age = age;
      }

      public int getCount(){
          return this.count;
      }
}
```

How would I include a counter (within the getter/setter) that would increase by however many times the function (let's call it AskForAge in this case) is called? For example if the function was called once, the counter would be 1, if it was called twice it would be 2, etc?

Comment: Why does a class called `Age` have a field called `age`? Why are you setting `this.age` to itself in `setAge()`? Why are you passing a `count` parameter? Why aren't you using it? Why don't you have a `count` field on the class? So many questions...

Answer (score 5):

> How would I include a counter (within the getter/setter) that would
>   increase by however many times the function (let's call it AskForAge
>   in this case) is called?

one approach is to simply create a static field like so:

```
public static int count = 0;

public void setAge(int age){
     this.age = age;
     count++;
}

public int getCount(){
    return count;
}
```

However, if you want to make `count` an `instance` field then I want to advise that would only count the number of times that particular `object` has called the `setAge(int age)` method.

```
private int count = 0;

public void setAge(int age){
    this.age = age;
    this.count++;
}

public int getCount(){
    return this.count;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, Simply create a static variable and increment counter value in getter/setter methods.